# C# DO While loop - Hangman

Tags: c#

I'm in the process of learning to code using C#. I have not been able to figure out why my loop won't end after 10 entries into my Hangman program, although the program works if set at a lesser number such as 6. I'm using a do while loop, and, when set to 10, I keep getting what seems to be an infinite loop, as it just keeps repeating and not ending as expected. I have no compiler errors. This is an assignment. Any help is appreciated. Here is the code I have wrote:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace hangman_projectW4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //variable list
            char letter0 = 'k';
            char letter1 = 'i';
            char letter2 = 'd';
            char letter3 = 'd';
            char letter4 = 'e';
            char letter5 = 'r';
            char letter;
            int score = 0;
            string user = "";

            //inputs inputs
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            user = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Hi! Welcome to Hangman.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Player, please enter a letter at prompt.");
            Console.Write("_________________________________________________________________");
            user = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

            do
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a letter: ");
            letter = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            user = Console.ReadLine();
            if (letter == letter0 || letter == letter1 || letter == letter2 || letter == letter3 || letter == letter4 || letter == letter5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You guessed correctly!");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect. Try Again.");
                score++;
            }

            user = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a letter: ");
            letter = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            user = Console.ReadLine();
            if (letter == letter0 || letter == letter1 || letter == letter2 || letter == letter3 || letter == letter4 || letter == letter5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You guessed correctly!");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect. Try Again.");
                score++;
            }

            user = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a letter: ");
            letter = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            user = Console.ReadLine();
            if (letter == letter0 || letter == letter1 || letter == letter2 || letter == letter3 || letter == letter4 || letter == letter5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You guessed correctly!");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect. Try Again.");
                score++;
            }

            user = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a letter: ");
            letter = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            user = Console.ReadLine();
            if (letter == letter0 || letter == letter1 || letter == letter2 || letter == letter3 || letter == letter4 || letter == letter5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You guessed correctly!");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect. Try Again.");
                score++;
            }

            user = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a letter: ");
            letter = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            user = Console.ReadLine();
            if (letter == letter0 || letter == letter1 || letter == letter2 || letter == letter3 || letter == letter4 || letter == letter5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You guessed correctly!");                

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect. Try Again.");
                score++;
            }

            user = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a letter: ");
            letter = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            user = Console.ReadLine();
            if (letter == letter0 || letter == letter1 || letter == letter2 || letter == letter3 || letter == letter4 || letter == letter5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You guessed correctly!");               

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect. Try Again.");
                score++;
            }

            user = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a letter: ");
            letter = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            user = Console.ReadLine();
            if (letter == letter0 || letter == letter1 || letter == letter2 || letter == letter3 || letter == letter4 || letter == letter5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You guessed correctly!");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect. Try Again.");
                score++;
            }

            user = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a letter: ");
            letter = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            user = Console.ReadLine();
            if (letter == letter0 || letter == letter1 || letter == letter2 || letter == letter3 || letter == letter4 || letter == letter5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You guessed correctly!");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect. Try Again.");
                score++;
            }

            user = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a letter: ");
            letter = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            user = Console.ReadLine();
            if (letter == letter0 || letter == letter1 || letter == letter2 || letter == letter3 || letter == letter4 || letter == letter5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You guessed correctly!");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect. Try Again.");
                score++;
            }

            user = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a letter: ");
            letter = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            user = Console.ReadLine();
            if (letter == letter0 || letter == letter1 || letter == letter2 || letter == letter3 || letter == letter4 || letter == letter5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You guessed correctly!");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect. Try Again.");
                score++;
            }
            }while (score <= 10);

            //outputs
            user = Console.ReadLine();
            user = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("_________________________________________________________________");
            user = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Guessed Incorrectly: " + score);
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Thank you for playing Hangman.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if there is a better way to write the code so that I'm not repeating the if else ten times...pointers would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Don't just drop all your code here. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please and provide us with a minimal, complete, and verifiable code example.

Comment: This is a good opportunity to step through your code in a debugger as it executes.  Keeping in mind what the loop condition is checking, is the loop modifying that value as you expect it to?  If you have an infinite loop, then it would seem that `score` is always `<= 10`.  Debug and find out why it isn't being modified the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you try hard enough it will end. Once you've reached your score of 11 or more, your code may just continue and continue asking for another try. Stop copying code. Be smarter and minimize your code! Your loop repeats the same thing over and over again without even checking whether you have already reached more than 10 points (`score`).

Shorten your loop to something like this:

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a letter: ");
    letter = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (letter == letter0 ||
        letter == letter1 ||
        letter == letter2 ||
        letter == letter3 ||
        letter == letter4 ||
        letter == letter5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You guessed correctly!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect. Try Again.");
        score++;
    }
} while (score <= 10);
```

Next step is to add all your letters to a collection or list and shorten your `if` statement. ;-)

Comment: hitting 10 times X and I will win the game ;o)

Comment: Thanks QC. Though isn't that the purpose of my score++? To keep track of the number of attempts at the incorrect prompt? Or was it just repeating because of the number of times I copied my if else within the do while. I'm trying to understand the logic...

Comment: Your whole loop is wrong in so many ways: repeated code, user variable assigned all the time, incorrect scoring etc. Maybe best to read another hangman example, learn how it works, then write your own. Sample: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/HangMan-C-version-e0d17f1b

Comment: @SirRufo: yes. that code sample is taking the main issues away: repeated code and the unnecessary clearance of the console. The scoring isn't working either, the loop only exits when 11 or more incorrect attempts etc. Joshua better starts from scratch again and debugs his work.